# Moving multiple boxes in figure?

Tags: matlab, drag-and-drop, figure

I already have the functions required to drag and drop a single box in a figure in MATLAB. The code I wrote fills the figure with several boxes. With another loop I filled the figure with more boxes (which hold different information in string form).

These two sets of boxes are related by the numbers I placed in their UserData (corresponding numbers; for each box, there's another with the same UserData content). By finding boxes containing the same UserData (and thus relating them) I want to be able to relocate a member of the first set of boxes to the same position relative to the corresponding member of the second set of boxes, by means of right clicking on the box I just dragged (uicontextmenu).

```
function recallfcn(hObject,eventdata)
for ydx=1:2
    diag_detail=get(gco,'UserData');   % This line should be in the drag fcn
    diag_pos=get(gco,'Position');      % So should this one (for current objects)
    xvar=diag_pos(1,1);
    yvar=diag_pos(1,2);
    detail=[diag_detail ydx]; 
    set(findobj('UserData',detail),'Position',[xvar+(ydx-1.5) yvar+0.5 0.8 0.8]);
end
end

% ydx is only there to add another level of detail as I'm actually looking to move     
% two boxes of the 'first kind', each of which have 2 numbers in user data, the first  
% number being the same, and the second number distinguishing the first box from the 
% second. The premise is the same.
```

Comment: Yes, it should work as you described. So what's the question?

Comment: When I right click on a box I'm using its handle. Once I move a member of the second set of boxes I use the function findobj(.) which is supposed to return a handle of the other box (the one I want to relocate relative to the first one I mentioned). There seems to be some kind of clash due to the fact that two handles are in use, and the code does nothing - returning no error message, either. I'll edit the question to include some of the code which I hoped to use for the relocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `findall` instead of `findobj`, in case the handles of the objects are not visible from the outside. Other than that I don't see why your code wouldn't work.

Here's an example:

```
%# make a figure with two buttons, same userData
fh=figure,
uicontrol('userdata',[2 3],'parent',fh)
uicontrol('userData',[2 3],'units','normalized','position',[0.5 0.5,0.1 0.1],'parent',fh)

%# change color to red
set(findall(fh,'userData',[2 3]),'backgroundcolor','r')

%# move to the same position
set(findall(fh,'userData',[2 3]),'position',[0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1])
```

Answer (score 3):

[As Jonas alludes to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670504/moving-multiple-boxes-in-figure/6680909#6680909), the [`'HandleVisibility'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#HandleVisibility) of an object will determine if the object shows up in its parent's list of children, and thus if it will be returned by functions like [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html). The standard fix is to use the function [FINDALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findall.html) instead.

However, the [`'HandleVisibility'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#HandleVisibility) also comes into play in determining whether or not an object can become the [current object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gco.html) (i.e. returnable by the function GCO). If it is set to `'off'`, then that object can't become the current object. Additionally, if the [`'HandleVisibility'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#HandleVisibility) of the *parent figure* of an object is set to `'off'` then none of its children (including said object) can become the current object.

If `'HandleVisibility'` is set to `'on'` or `'callback'` for all your objects and figures, then I think everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation along with Jonas' example helped me understand a bit more about handles in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

you should inverse the ordre of x and y vector, and you can use just one loop, the changment in your code is :

```
x2=x(end:-1:1); % invers the ordre
y2=y(end:-1:1);

for i=1:length(x)

set(hLine,'xdata',x(i),'ydata',y(i)); % move the point using set
                                  % to change the cooridinates.

set(hLine2,'xdata',x2(i),'ydata',y2(i));

 M(i)=getframe(gcf);

end
```